# how to replace consecutive nans elements with the row above

Tags: matlab

I have the following matrix

```
A = [ 0    0  
      0    0 
      1   -1 
    NaN  NaN 
    NaN  NaN 
      0    0 
    NaN  NaN 
    NaN  NaN]
```

I want to replace all the `NaN` rows with the rows above it. For the matrix above, this would be

```
A = [0  0 
     0  0 
     1  -1 
     1  -1 
     1  -1 
     0   0 
     0   0 
     0   0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this can be vectorized...the simpler solution would probably be a loop:

```
newRow = [];
nans = isnan(A(:,1));
for ii = 1:size(A,1)

    if nans(ii)

        %# first row might be NaN -- skip it
        if ii==1
            continue; end

        %# for all other rows:
        if isempty(newRow) 
            newRow = A(ii-1,:); end

        A(ii,:) = newRow;

    else
        newRow = [];
    end

end
```

Answer (score 4):

One idea is to first create a *compressed* matrix `B`, which does not contain the rows with a `NaN` and then expand this matrix again to be of the same length as the original matrix:

```
mask = any(isnan(A), 2);
B = A(~mask, :);
result = B(cumsum(~mask), :);
```

Comment: What a nice solution! (edit: but I just noted that it does not work if A has NaNs in the first row, right? Nevertheless it is nice.)

Comment: @H.Muster: That's by design :) The OP asked to replace a NaN by the value **above** but the first row has no values above. If somebody provides a clearer spec, I'll think how to solve it.

Comment: +1: very elegant! How about `mask = isnan(A(:,1))`? Saves a pass through `any`...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: Yes, good point! Works as long as the whole row contains NaNs. And should be a bit faster, too.